# CSS module `:hover .child` not working

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app, css-modules

I have the following scss:

```
.skillBox {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px #ccc;
  padding: 1em;

  &:hover {
    padding: 3em;
    .d-none {
      display: inline-block !important;
    }
  }

  &:hover .d-none {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}
```

On hover, I get the `padding:3em` but both the nested, and inline child rule didn't work, ie `.d-none` class wasn't overridden.

What's the right way of writing the rule with CSS module?

I'm trying out CSS module with CRA and [custom-react-scripts](https://github.com/kitze/custom-react-scripts) with `sass` and `modules` turned on (`REACT_APP_SASS_MODULES=true`).

Or perhaps I should use `styled components` instead? Was trying to figure out which one to go for for react apps.

Comment: I think your CSS looks correct. A word of advice - if you need to customise create-react-app to be happy working with it don't use create-react-app. You lose many of the benefits as soon as you go off piste with it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code to solve your problem

```
.skillBox {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px #ccc;
  padding: 3em;
  background: red;
  &:hover {
    &.d-none {
      background: black;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 20px;
    }
  }
}

.d-none {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}


<div class="skillBox">
  Parrent
  <div class="d-none">Childred</div>
</div>
```

Exmaple :: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqQNJX[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqQNJX)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your CSS. See the demo below.

```
.skillBox {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px #ccc;
  padding: 1em;

  .d-none{
    display: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    padding: 3em;
    .d-none {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/djQoow

Answer (score 0):

In case if element with `skillbox` and `d-none` class are siblings below is the css for that

```
.skillBox {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px #ccc;
  padding: 1em;

  &:hover {
    padding: 3em;
  }
}

.dnone {
  display: none;
}

.skillBox:hover ~ .dnone {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/hixamotuku/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

So I realise CSS Modules created a customised classname for `.d-none` and applying that classname worked.

So I changed the classname altogether making it an entirely new class that overrides `.d-none`.

```
.skillBox {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px #ccc;
  padding: 1em;

  &:hover {
    .dNone {
      display: inline-block !important;
    }
  }
}
```

And applying by adding them as an array then joining them together:

```
<i className={['fas fa-times-circle d-none', styles.faTimesCircle, styles.dNone].join(' ')} onClick={this.onDelete} />
```